# Derivation of distribution

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

There is a problem from Bertsekas and Tsitsiklis "Introduction to Probability" chapter 4.

**Problem 1.**
*X is a random variable that is uniformly distributed between -1 and 1. Find the PDF of*  $Y=-log(|x|)$.

The solution to this is the folowing:

$P(Y\leqslant y)=P(-log|x|\leqslant y) = P(log(|x|) \geqslant -y)=P(x \geqslant e^{-y}) + P(x\leqslant -e^{-y}) = 1-e^{-y} \quad for \quad y\geqslant 0$

I am not able to grasp the idea why latter expression is valid only for  y >= 0. However it is obvious that is is true since $\quad \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y}dy = 1 \quad$ ensures that $\quad P(Y\leqslant y) \quad$  is correct CDF.

Comment: If $y<0$ then $\exp\{-y\} > 1$ and $\mathsf P(|X| > 1) = 0$. So $\mathsf P(Y \le y) = 0$ if $y < 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As X is only takes values from -1 to 1 -log(|x|) is always positive, i.e. for y < 0 the probability would be 0 and not $1-e^{-y}$ which would be less than 1.
So the calculation only holds true for $y \geq 0$. You can easily see this as if $e^{-y} > 1$ then $P(x \geq e^{-y})$ and $P(x \leq -e^{-y})$ would both be 0.